# Manhua: Cultivator emerges or reincarnates after a long time of absence

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

Couple months ago I remember reading a cultivation manga at my usual site, Mangabat, and now I have no idea what the title was.

**Characters:**

The main character is a young looking male who is quite reluctant (laidback) to do anything that is requested of him. He is supposedly extremely powerful and friend and/or master to a sect master who looks like a dwarf (short, beard) but actually isn't a dwarf. The dwarf looking sect master is really worried that the mc might get angry and just destroy the whole sect in one go.

Main character is know for his temper. If he get's angry then most of the time someone or everyone who made him angry is going to die.

Sect master provided him with a advisor who informs him about the sect rules.

**Most memorable scenes:**

Dwarf looking sect master wishes him to become successor for the next sect master (to avoid someone else getting it?), mc is quite reluctant but ultimately accepts his request. Advisor now and then tells him to attend this and that while following the rules to get the successor position. Later it is planned that someone else steps up and takes the position because mc doesnt want it.

I remember the mc sitting in something akin to a beach chair in the sect master's garden and drinking alcohol with the advisor next to him.

**General information:**

I'm quite sure that this manga was actually a manhua (chinese production).

**What it isn't:**

(This will get filled as I get suggestions and rule out manga.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you describe the MC's hair length and colour?

Comment: To my memory his hair length was long and the color black(?)

Comment: could be [above all gods](https://m.mangabat.com/read-ps393537). there a number of differences though - light grey hair, the short old man is an elder but the rest of it matches exactly.

Comment: Yes that is it! Thank you finally I can rest yet again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: ***[Above All Gods](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/above-all-gods)***. Thank somebody for the answer.

From Anime-Planet:

> The ancient Sirius of the Red King, the capital of the Demon Lord, was besieged by everyone, jealous of heaven, besieged in Chiyan Ridge, judged by heaven, deprived of the foundation of the fairy path, the throne of the magic path, and died However, the ancient Sirius was born 500 years later with a mysterious ancient jade! The enemies of the last life, the revenge of this life, the shame of the last life, the snow of this life! I am an ancient Sirius, and I speak for myself ...